# Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://-n 'username'

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube

Now I Study kubernates
i faced an issue when i try to Create Mongo And monge express nodes

This is mongo express node logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrLj5.png)
This is mongo node logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrlej.png)

And These is My yaml Files
Mongo-express deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-configmap
                  key: database_url
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
```

My Config Map File
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHGkp.png)

My Mongo Deployment File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
              hostPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

My Secrets File
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cflol.png)

When I Try To Start minikube service mongo-express-service
It Open [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVPyo.png)
And Not Working

Comment: Please don't include images when it is trivial to copy and paste the image's test instead. Images may not outlive the question **and** they inhibit our ability to reference their content.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MongoDB but you're first image (see above caveat) contains the error that the connection string is not defined correctly  `mongodb://-n 'username' ...` so you should start debugging there.

Comment: You use the environment variable `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER` but this appears to not be one of the supported variables see [Usage](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express?tab=readme-ov-file#usage-docker)